# Hide an element after 5 seconds only CSS does not work on Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

For hiding an element after 5 seconds, I have used below code.

But it does not work in Firefox.

```css
.classname {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">This will hide</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your code works for me in chrome and your problem's solution works for me in firefox... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with the code above:

- The animation is not the same for all browsers: one is animating the `visibility` (webkit), the other one is animation the `overflow` (standard).
- The `overflow` property is [not animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).
- Firefox has a history of issues with the `visibility` property (this is not your fault but a problem of Firefox itself, you can find many questions on SO related to it).

Because of the way in which you are running the animation (with a duration of 0s), you can trick Firefox by using the `from` in the CSS animation. The thing is that Firefox is not animating the `visibility`, but it will apply the style in the `from` part of the animation anyway, so you'll get the desired effect.

```css
.classname {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">This will hide</div>
```

If the duration of the animation was higher than 0 seconds, this solution wouldn't work; but as the change is automatic, it works fine (and it will not affect the rest of the browsers).

---

The advantages of this solution:

- The behavior is the same in all the browsers.
- The hidden text is not selectable.

The disadvantages:

- This is a workaround and not how things should be done.
- It does not work if the duration of the effect is higher than 0s.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fixed `width` and `height` for your block (in `%` or `px`) and `opacity` instead `visibility` — http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/wek6x4Ln/11/:

```
.classname {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: css-animation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    animation: css-animation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes css-animation {
    to {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes css-animation {
    to {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```